# Closing Oracle connection?

Tags: jdbc

We always hear that we should close the connection once we are done with a transaction. My question here is: even if we don't close the connection, the garbage collector will reclaim the memory once we are out of the method inside of which we are creating the connection. so what's the actual issue, even if we don't close the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GC doesn't help you here, because it's not about memory.

A connection is a scarce resource on the *database server*, not in your *app client*.  If you clean up *your* memory without telling the *server* to do the same you'll leak a connection that may not be reclaimed.  Eventually you'll run out.

Same with ResultSet - it's a cursor.

You must *always* close all SQL resources - Connection, Statement, and ResultSet - in individual finally blocks, wrapped in try/catch blocks, in reverse order of acquisition.

```
public class JdbcTemplate {

    public Object exampleSqlOperation(Connection c) throws SQLException {
        Object results = null;

        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
           // SQL stuff here
           // Load into results Object - data structure
        } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace(); // Better to log it.
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtils.close(rs);  
            DatabaseUtils.close(st);
        }

        return results;
    }
}

public class DatabaseUtils {
    public static void close(Connection c) {
        try {
            if (c != null) c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // Same for Statement, ResultSet
}
```

Comment: Thanks duffymo.As we say connection is scarce resource. what is so special about 
database connection that we call it scarce and expensive?
just to to get more understanding on it, As you said "Eventually you'll run out." Is there
a maximum limit of connection on database server ?Can't we get 
connection for every request even if we dont close some of the connections in between?

Comment: the database server only sets aside so many; that's what makes them scarce.  (Nothing is infinite on any computer I use.)  No, once you run out that's it.